# Why the button clicked is not the winner even though its id matches the winning number?

Tags: javascript, random, attributes, click, element

I want to create three buttons and only one of them should be the winner. When I click on the winner button, the output will be ***"Congratulations. You have found the winner button!***" and if the clicked button is not the winning one, the output will be "***Keep trying.***"

The winner button will be the one whose id will match a randomly chosen value between 1 and 3. This value will be generated within the function "**WinnerButton(buttonCnt)**" with the help of the method "**Math.random()**".

```
<p>Which button is the winner ?</p>

<button type = "submit" id = "1" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)"></button>
<button type = "submit" id = "2" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)"></button>
<button type = "submit" id = "3" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)"></button>

<pre id = "output"></pre>

<script>
  let buttonCnt = 3;
 
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');

  function WinnerButton(buttonCnt) {
    let Winner = Math.ceil(Math.random() * buttonCnt);
      return Winner;
  }
  
  function handleClick(clicked_id) {
      if (Number(clicked_id) === WinnerButton(buttonCnt)) {
        output.textContent = "Congratulations. You have found the winner button!"
      } else {
        output.textContent = "Keep trying."
      }
  }

</script>
```

The problem is that if I check the winner button in the console and click it, there are certain cases when the clicked button is not the winner. If you click on the image below, you will see that even though the console says that the winner button is number 3, I receive the message "Keep trying" if I click on it. I know that you don't see that I clicked on the third button, but you can trust me that I did it.

I don't understand why is this happening. Can you please explain me? I don't want a straight solution, but an explanation of what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much.

[Screenshoot with the example mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug7gS.png)

Comment: You're creating a new random winner on each click of a button so the winning button will keep shifting. Maybe call the `WinnerButton` function and assign the value to a variable _outside_ of the click handler.

Comment: You should probably study up on asynchronous behavior.

Comment: `console.log(WinnerButton(3),WinnerButton(3),WinnerButton(3),WinnerButton(3),WinnerButton(3));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only once use function `WinnerButton` because if you use it in `handleClick` it every time change the winner id.

```js
let buttonCnt = 3;
let winnerId = WinnerButton(buttonCnt)

const output = document.querySelector('#output');

function WinnerButton(buttonCnt) {
    let Winner = Math.ceil(Math.random() * buttonCnt);
    return Winner;
}

function handleClick(clicked_id) {
    if (Number(clicked_id) === winnerId) {
        output.textContent = "Congratulations. You have found the winner button!"
    } else {
        output.textContent = "Keep trying."
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Which button is the winner ?</p>

<button type = "submit" id = "1" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)">1</button>
<button type = "submit" id = "2" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)">2</button>
<button type = "submit" id = "3" onclick = "handleClick(this.id)">3</button>

<pre id = "output"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you every time generates the result then every click on the buttons generating a new value. I took out from the function the random number generation.

I counted the number of the buttons also dinamically so later you can add more buttons into the game.

```js
const buttonCnt = document.querySelectorAll("button").length;
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const result = Math.ceil(Math.random() * buttonCnt);

function handleClick(clicked_id) {
  output.textContent = +clicked_id === result ? "Congratulations. You have found the winner button!" : "Keep trying."
}
```

```html
<p>Which button is the winner ?</p>

<button type="submit" id="1" onclick="handleClick(this.id)">1</button>
<button type="submit" id="2" onclick="handleClick(this.id)">2</button>
<button type="submit" id="3" onclick="handleClick(this.id)">3</button>

<pre id = "output"></pre>
```

Comment: I've put that first into the editor to working on the solution... :(

Comment: @exphoenee if you make a mistake like that you can easily delete* the answer, work on it, and then undelete it to save any unwanted downvotes. *not really deleted.